# how to paas doc of type Document in Junit to get clientID through getClientid IN webservice using SOAP

Tags: java, junit, documentum

There is command which returns Document Type value.

```
i.e context.getRequestContext().getDocument()
```

here context is of type OperationContext.

I am writing a JUnit for a webservice method. This service is based on SOAP.
So I need to pass Document into `getClientId(dcmt);` so that it should return clientID. Otherwise this will throw NullPointerException.

```
clientId=getClientID(context.getRequestContext().getDocument());
```

So how can I pass the Document into junit so that it will return clientID fron server.

Comment: are you consuming dfs web service?

Comment: no it is java based web Service

Comment: how do you implement access to the Documentum repository? this is important for your question

Comment: Can you post your junit code?